# Forward email with attachment

Tags: python, email, imap, forwarding

I want to resend email with attachments in Python. I have this code for sending email but how can I reference to attachment in another email?

Sending

```py
def show_emails():
    M.select()
    typ, data = M.search(None, 'All') 
    for num in data[0].split(): 
        typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        parser = Parser()
        email = parser.parsestr(data[0][1])
        print "MESSAGE NUMBER %s" % (num)
        print 'Raw Date:'
        print email.get('Date')
        print "From:"
        print email.get('From') 
        print "Subject: "
        print email.get('Subject')
```

And this code is for sending

```py
msg = MIMEMultipart()

mfrom = 'from@abc.com'
mto = 'to@abc.com'

msg['Subject'] = 'test'
msg['From'] = mfrom
msg['To'] = mto
msg['Date'] = formatdate()

# Open the file to scan in binary mode
fp = open('/path/to/file', 'rb')
attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="filename"')
fp.close()
msg.attach(attachment)
```

I know I need to check if there is any attachment. And how can I reference to attachment and forward it?

```py
if msg.is_multipart():
        for part in msg.walk(): 
        fileName = part.get_filename()
        if bool(fileName):
            print "Attachment: %s " % (decode_header(fileName)[0][0])
        else:
            print "No attachments"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just reference it: that's what RFCs 4467-9 were for, but those weren't implemented by many servers and at this point I think they're dead. You have to download the attachment and send it as if you were sending a local file.